# Rerun the java code after certain pause

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to threads. I have a scenario where i am publishing data to external system. If publish fails due to any error (which i will know based on the return status), I have to retry again after certain amount of time.

I am planning to due this with Thread.sleep. Is it good to use or there is any better way of doing it?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

pseudo code:-

```
public void publish()  throws InterruptedException {
int status=1;

for ( int i=0;i<3 i++)
 {
   status= //java code to publish external system;

      if( status ==0 ) //0 means success
        {
         break;
        }
      else
      {
      Thread.sleep(4000);
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code, what have you tried  ????

Comment: Your main thread should wait to join on thread which is pushing data and get return status. User Thread.join

Comment: @BhavikAmbani added pseudo code for your reference

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on code review.

Answer (score 1):

First, your example is still single threaded (and that thread will be paused when you sleep(), which you seem to know). However, as a solution to your described problem a retry loop with a `Thread.sleep()` and a growing `backoffInterval` sounds like a reasonable approach

```
long backoffInterval = 1000; // <-- 1000 milliseconds
while (true) {
    if (sendMessage()) { // <-- did the message send complete?
        break; // <-- stop if it did.
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(backoffInterval); // <-- sleep
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    backoffInterval += 1000; // <-- increase the backoffInterval.
}
```